# Trying to create a widget that submits a form and takes you to another search page

Tags: entities

The original example [`http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/apachesolr-and-facetapi`](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/apachesolr-and-facetapi) uses an auto submitter, which I don't want. I'm trying to modify it to use checkboxes and submit with a submit button, however that doesn't appear to be working. I can select different boxes and submit, but it doesn't take me to another search page.

```
class ResourceLibraryWidget extends FacetapiWidget {
   /**
   * Renders the form.
   */
  public function execute() {
    $elements = &$this->build[$this->facet['field alias']];
    $elements = drupal_get_form('resource_library_facetapi_select', $elements);
  }
}

function resource_library_facetapi_select($form, &$form_state, $elements) {
  // Build options from facet elements.
  //$options = array('' => t('- Select -'));
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element['#active']) {
      continue;
    }
    $options[serialize($element['#query'])] = $element['#markup']; //. '(' . $element['#count'] . ')';
  }

  $form['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $options,
    //'#attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-auto-submit')),
    'default_value' => '',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Find Resources'),
    //'#attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-use-ajax', 'ctools-auto-submit-click')),
  );

  // Lets add autosubmit js functionality from ctools.
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'ctools') . '/js/auto-submit.js';
  // Add javascript that hides Filter button.
  //$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'example') . '/js/example-hide-submit.js';

  $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'resource-library-checkbox-facet';

  return $form;
}
```

Why isn't it working the way I intend? I'm trying to change different values on the submit button, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question, so I will assume that you are missing the following:

```
/**
 * Submit handler for facet form.
 */
function resource_library_facetapi_select_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = array(
    $_GET['q'],
    array('query' => unserialize($form_state['values']['select'])),
  );
}
```

Comment: No, I didn't include that, but that's on there.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander So this function exists, is called and the `$form_state['redirect']` is set?

Comment: function resource_library_facetapi_select_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = array($_GET['q'], array('query' => unserialize($form_state['values']['select'])));
}

Comment: It should be called by   $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Find Resources'),
    //'#attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-use-ajax', 'ctools-auto-submit-click')),
  ); - correct?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander `resource_library_facetapi_select_submit` follows a naming convention and should be called in your case, yes. But just in case, can you verify this by adding a `drupal_set_message` or something similar?

Comment: Where should I put the drupal_set_message? I'll be honest, I'm not entirely sure of the way that Drupal is calling the submit function.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Put the `drupal_set_message` in the first line of the `resource_library_facetapi_select_submit` function.

Comment: function resource_library_facetapi_select_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(print_r($form_state['redirect'] = array($_GET['q'], array('query' => unserialize($form_state['values']['select'], true)))));
} gives me a value of "1" in my messages.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander That is normal, because the result of the assignment is TRUE when the assignment has been executed without an error, and TRUE gets converted to `1` in `print_r`. But it already shows that the submit function is called. Try to set `$form_state['redirect'] = 'node';`, just to see if this redirects to the node page, that will tell us, if the most simple redirect is respected.

Comment: I already tried a simple redirect with google.com, and that worked correctly.

Comment: However $form_state['redirect'] = 'node'; did not, it left it at the same page.

Comment: But this is for a search page, so there shouldn't be a node, correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12977/discussion-between-berliner-and-andrew-alexander)

Comment: I added more information and finally got info from $form_state['values']

Comment: The submitted values can't be right. Check in your form builder function the value of `$options` after it has been build. Feel free to paste the result here or in the chat, I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: I figured this all out. I'll post the answer soon.